# How can i solve Call to undefined method DateTime::diff()?

Tags: php, date, time

```
$today= new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'));
$dob= new DateTime($user_dob);
$diff = $today->diff($dob);
return $diff->y .' Year';
```

I am trying to calculate age but its showing error `Call to undefined method DateTime::diff()` how can i solve this problem? i m using PHP Version  5.4.24

Comment: Are you absolutely sure about your PHP version? What is the output of `echo phpversion();`?

Comment: sorry it was 5.2. i solved it by another method . thanks

Answer (score 0):

internal objects in php5, on failure, can return null in the __construct. You can check for:

```
if (null !== $today) {
    $diff = $today->diff($dob);
    return $diff->y .' Year';
}
```

The value that is being returned by `date('Y-m-d')` would also help understanding why the method is failing

Answer (score 0):

In the answers there is a good option with calculating the days.
But for correct calculation, use "floor" instead of "round"

```
$start = new DateTime('2020-06-20');
$end = new DateTime();
$days = floor(($end->format('U') - $start->format('U')) / (60*60*24));
```

The system does not allow me to leave a comment